# Dynamically assign obtained results to variables in Python

Tags: python

I have an API response for listing out information of all **Volumes**. I want to loop through the response and get the value of the `name` and assign each one of them dynamically to each **url**.

This is my main API endpoint which returns the following:

```
[{'source': None, 'serial': '23432', 'created': '2018-11- 
12T04:27:14Z', 'name': 'v001', 'size': 
456456}, {'source': None, 'serial': '4364576', 
'created': '2018-11-12T04:27:16Z', 'name': 'v002', 
'size': 345435}, {'source': None, 'serial': 
'6445645', 'created': '2018-11-12T04:27:17Z', 'name': 'v003', 'size': 
23432}, {'source': None, 
'serial': 'we43235', 'created': '2018-11-12T04:27:20Z', 
'name': 'v004', 'size': 35435}]
```

I'm doing this to get the value of `'name'`

```
 test_url = 'https://0.0.0.0/api/1.1/volume'
 test_data = json.loads(r.get(test_url, headers=headers, 
 verify=False).content.decode('UTF-8'))

 new_data = [{
         'name': value['name']
 } for value in test_data]

 final_data = [val['name'] for val in new_data]

 for k in final_data:
         print(k)
```

`k` prints out all the values in `name`, but i'm stuck at where i want to be able to use it in assigning different API endpoints. Now, `k` returns

```
v001
v002
v003
v004
```

I want to assign each one of them to different endpoints like below:

```
url_v001 = test_url + v001
url_v002 = test_url + v002
url_v003 = test_url + v003
url_v004 = test_url + v004
```

I want this to be dynamically done, because there may be more than 4 volume names returned by my main API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be good to do that, but the best way is to use a dictionary:

```
d={}
for k in final_test:
    d['url_'+k] = test_url + k
```

Or much better in a dictionary comprehension:

```
d={'url_'+k:test_url + k for k in final_test}
```

And now:

```
print(d)
```

Both reproduce:

```
{'url_v001': 'https://0.0.0.0/api/1.1/volumev001', 'url_v002': 'https://0.0.0.0/api/1.1/volumev002', 'url_v003': 'https://0.0.0.0/api/1.1/volumev003', 'url_v004': 'https://0.0.0.0/api/1.1/volumev004'}
```

To use `d`:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print(k+',',v)
```

Outputs:

```
url_v001, https://0.0.0.0/api/1.1/volumev001
url_v002, https://0.0.0.0/api/1.1/volumev002
url_v003, https://0.0.0.0/api/1.1/volumev003
url_v004, https://0.0.0.0/api/1.1/volumev004
```

Comment: I feel like this could easily be simplified into a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: @Tomothy32 Edited mine.

Comment: @U9-Forward Thanks very much! Appreciate your help. But if its put in a dictionary, how do i use each URL separately? Like, i use each url and loop through them to get my desired values.

Comment: @Bharath Edited mine, also see the documentation, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries, happy to help :-)

Comment: @U9-Forward thanks for your help. Just one more, when i do `print(d)` it prints out 4 duplicates (like it prints 4 lines (dictionary) of the same first line).

Comment: @Bharath Why? how come, try it again.

Comment: Nah nah, disregard my comment, its all good. I was printing inside the for loop. Its all good now.